# How do I format an iPhone's app email as a 'form' with input fields?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, email

Can somebody explain to me how I can present an email to the iPhone-App-User that has input fields that the User should fill in before sending ??

Simple Example: The user should input their name....

> Blockquote

```
NSString *emailBody = @"\
        <html><head>\
 </head><body>\
 <form>First name:<input type="text" name="firstname" /></form>\
 </body></html>";

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

> Blockquote

With the above example I get a compiler error "**Expected ',' or ';' before 'text'**".
Any help would be much appreciated. I tried searching for the answer but didn't get a solution.

Thanks

Comment: First, you can't have input fields in an email. Second, you need to escape your double quotes or change them to single quotes. The double quote before 'text' is ending your string definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U first input all details of user in a simple view and store in different different variable;
ie.Nsstring *name=name.text;

like that u store inputed data from user.

after that u make a new nsstring *body.
in body string u simply append all strings in formated way.
finaly in the last u

[picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];

Comment: Ok, I get it. I was a step ahead of myself. I need to make a Questionnaire for the User to fill in and then use the data to build the email body. 
Thanks for the help.